# Every Cauchy sequence in a normed vector space is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

But what about Cauchy sequences in non-normed vector spaces? How can we even measure a vector in a sequence if there is no norm?

Comment: For a sequence to be Cauchy, there must be a metric, which arises from a norm

Comment: What is a Cauchy sequence in a topological space which has not a metric?

Comment: Is a metric space necessarily a normed vector space?

Comment: @eepperly16 Every norm induces a metric, but there are metrics which cannot arise from any norm. The discrete metric is one simple example.

Comment: Nope, it's totally possible to have a metric not coming from a norm.

Comment: @sequence In general, a metric space need not even be a vector space.

Comment: Do there necessarily exist Cauchy sequences in metric spaces?

Comment: Of course it does. Every constant sequence is Cauchy, for instance.

Comment: @sequence Yes, the following definition makes sense in any metric space:  a sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $N$ such that $d(x_n, x_m) < \epsilon$ for all $n,m \geq N$. A constant sequence is always a Cauchy sequence in any metric space, so yes, they exist in any metric space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a cauchy sequence inside any metric space is bounded.

Notice that there exists a natural number $N$ such that $d(X_N,x_m)<1$ for all $m>N$.

Let $D=\max\limits_{i<N}d(x_N,x_i)$. Then the ball of radius $D+1$ centered at $X_N$ contains all of the sequence.

Comment: How do you know that $d(X_N, x_m)<1$? By definition, $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists N > 0$ such that if $m>n>N \implies d(x_n, x_m) < \varepsilon$. Then, if $N < n$, $d(x_N, x_m)\not<\epsilon$.

Comment: I am taking $n=N$ for this application. Notice that the variable $n$ does not appear.

Comment: But your $N$ is fixed, correct?

Comment: yes, $N$ is a natural number such that $d(x_N,x_m)<1$ for all $m>N$.

Comment: I see. I just got confused because I thought you used a different meaning of $N$.